# use autocomplete and drop-down together

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am using an Auto-Complete with ASP.NET MVC-5 App using JSON dataSource in Kendo UI... which is working fine, Now I want the drop-down as-well with auto-complete so when user typing value, program start filtering data but user can also drop-down and choose from list.....

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult GetAllFeeScheme_JSON()
    {        
        var allFeeScheme = FeeScheme_UOF.GetAllFeeScheme().ToList();

        return Json(allFeeScheme, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

### Partial_View

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model._FeeScheme.FeeSchemeDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
      <div class="col-md-6">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._FeeScheme.FeeSchemeDescription, new { id = "_FeeScheme_Input" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._FeeScheme.FeeSchemeDescription)
      </div>
 </div>
```

### Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#_FeeScheme_Input").kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 2,
        filter: 'contains',
        dataTextField: "FeeSchemeDescription",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: false,
            transport: {
                read: "/Qualification/GetAllFeeScheme_JSON"
            },
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: are you looking for a cascading dropdown affect using autocomplete? If so, i got you

Comment: Or are you willing to use the autocomplete for filtering the data from the same datasource and then show less values in the drop down list but the process of selection finishes when only one value is selected either in one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

solution is as following

```
 $("#_FeeScheme_Input").kendoComboBox({
        minLength: 1,
        filter: 'contains',
        dataTextField: "FeeSchemeDescription",
        dataValueField: "FeeSchemeID",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: false,
            transport: {
                read: "/Qualification/GetAllFeeScheme_JSON"
            },
        }
    });
```